# Dropzone.js php backend

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm currently trying out a new ajax-drag'n'drop-uploader that's still being updated daily. It's called [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). Now, I want to send a parameter along with the image. This can be done with

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("album", albumvalue);       
});
```

according to the docs. But my issue is that I don't know how to get the file parameters. Is there anyone with a wide knowledge of this plugin or how other ajax drag'n'drops work in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after looking at the response from the php upload script where I echoed out `$_FILES`, I found that the file uploaded is called `$_FILES['file']`, so you can use an upload script the same as when having a simple file-input.